# AngularJS - Directive parameter to accept either object or method

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I have a directive that accepts an object as a parameter. I would like to pass to this parameter either the object or a method that returns the object.

You can [view on JsFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/5wax9acc/2/) and here's the code:

**HTML**

```
<div ng-controller="Ctrl as vm">
  <my-directive user="{id: 1, name: 'Mike'}"></my-directive>
  <my-directive user="vm.getUser()"></my-directive>
</div>
```

**JS**

```
var app = angular.module('myApp', []);

app.controller('Ctrl', function() {
  var vm = this;

  this.getUser = function() {
    return {id: 2, name: 'John'};
  };
})

app.directive('myDirective', function() {
  return {
    bindToController: {
      user: '='
    },
    controller: function() {
      var vm = this;
    },
    controllerAs: 'vm',
    replace: true,
    restrict: 'EA',
    scope: {},
    template: '<div>Name: {{vm.user.name}}</div>'
  };
});
```

If I set the parameter's type to `=` like above, I get the following error:

```
Error: [$rootScope:infdig] 10 $digest() iterations reached. Aborting!
```

[AngularJS - Error Reference](https://docs.angularjs.org/error/$rootScope/infdig?p0=10&p1=%5B%5B%7B%22msg%22:%22fn:%20regularInterceptedExpression%22,%22newVal%22:%7B%22id%22:2,%22name%22:%22John%22%7D,%22oldVal%22:%7B%22id%22:2,%22name%22:%22John%22%7D%7D%5D,%5B%7B%22msg%22:%22fn:%20regularInterceptedExpression%22,%22newVal%22:%7B%22id%22:2,%22name%22:%22John%22%7D,%22oldVal%22:%22...%22%7D%5D,%5B%7B%22msg%22:%22fn:%20regularInterceptedExpression%22,%22newVal%22:%7B%22id%22:2,%22name%22:%22John%22%7D,%22oldVal%22:%22...%22%7D%5D,%5B%7B%22msg%22:%22fn:%20regularInterceptedExpression%22,%22newVal%22:%7B%22id%22:2,%22name%22:%22John%22%7D,%22oldVal%22:%22...%22%7D%5D,%5B%7B%22msg%22:%22fn:%20regularInterceptedExpression%22,%22newVal%22:%7B%22id%22:2,%22name%22:%22John%22%7D,%22oldVal%22:%22...%22%7D%5D%5D)

---

What's the right approach to achieve what I'm after?

Comment: This won't work.  You cannot bind a function to a directive like this.  Every time the directive is evaluated (when a `$digest` cycle happens), the function is returning a **new object with the same values as the previous object**, causing a new `$digest` cycle, causing the function to evaluate again, causing a new `$digest`, etc, until angular stops the inevitable infinite loop.

Comment: @Claies Thanks. Do you have any suggestions? Can you have a look at this approach ([https://jsfiddle.net/5wax9acc/4/](https://jsfiddle.net/5wax9acc/4/)) and let me know if you can see any downsides?

Comment: Your last fiddle looks like a good solution.

Comment: I agree that there doesn't seem to be any obvious downsides to the approach in the fiddle from the comments;  I might, however, suggest that this *feels like it could be* more of an XY problem;  It's possible that the *actual problem you are trying to solve* would be better served by changing the data structure or some other process where the need for passing a function would be eliminated.

Comment: Thanks guys. @Claies, the function is just a convenience in case passing an object straight is not ideal. A function can be useful to manipulate/find data before passing them into the directive. If you don't have any other suggested solutions I think I am going to post my answer as the solution.

Comment: the problem with using a function, though, as you describe it being a "convenience" and "manipulate/find data" is that you are going to have the same issues that `$digest` has.  two way binding won't work the way you expect once your data has been changed via this function.  This is the main reason I feel like this is an XY problem, because ultimately your solution is just trying to shoehorn in a function into a place it normally wouldn't be, and we can only *assume* that your function has some need to be there.

Comment: Agreed. This wouldn't work in all scenarios. In my case though, as in the example above, the parameter expects one way binding of a specific object structure. As long as the function adheres to the directive's requirement, then there shouldn't be any problems.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So I found it to be working with the following slight modifications to the directive:

```
...
bindToController: {
  userInput: '&user'
},
controller: function() {
  var vm = this;
  vm.user = (typeof vm.userInput === 'function' ? vm.userInput() : vm.userInput);
},
...
```

Here's the [solution on JsFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/5wax9acc/5/).

---

As mentioned by @Claies, this will work if the directive does not require binding for the specified parameter and the function should return a value synchronously.

Answer (score 0):

set two parameter for your directive one for obj and the other one for function and in your controller check which one has data:

```
<my-directive userObject="{id: 1, name: 'Mike'}" userFunction="vm.getUser()"></my-directive>
```

and controller would be like this:

```
    controller: function() {
    if($scope.userObject){
        //do something ...
    }else if ($scope.userFunction){
        //do something else ... 
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks. I am aware that this works though. I am specifically looking for a solution that uses the same property, as the input data expected is the same.